# Typescript: Copy One member of an Array Class into single array

Tags: javascript, angular, string, typescript, object

I have array class of DocumentItemSelection below:  `new Array<DocumentItemSelection>`. I want to copy just `documentNumber` class member into another `Array<string>`, while retaining same order.

What is a shorthand way of conducting this in Javascript/Typescript? Currently utilizing a for/foreach loop.

```
export class DocumentItemSelection {
  documentNumber: string;
  documentDate: Date;
  isCurrentOwnerFlag: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do this for you. Assuming that your `Array<DocumentItemSelection>` is stored in a const called `data`, then you simply ensure that the callback will return the value from the key `documentNumber`:

```
const documentNumbers = data.map(datum => datum.documentNumber);
```

TypeScript will automatically infer the type for `documentNumbers` array without issue: it will type if as `Array<string>` (or `string[]`).

See proof-of-concept example on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=30#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2wCuBbApgOwC4EktpQGU0Q1gsBLeDaAbwFgAoaaAE0VUywDlUAjNACcAXNAhZBFDAHMA3Exbtk6bLDD5Ra-PObQKEAMJJBgrgHkA7hiEAxcNNF948UmAw6AvkybBq4tupgogCCJmAAngA8CMpceATEpORUGAB80AC80ADaDLpKnNi8KAIi0ADkAGbO5QA0CmwcKlhaaKLWFnDqaAAUAJT1uvpGJuZWtvaiEkhogx61dA0FzcWlouV8YIJ1S01cre1ona39gyzDxqbYltaCdmAO0JVgIBCzTB4Aujo+fliNsSK-CEEBCYSi4kkMnSWVYgQAdCgwAAHHpwrCoTLpdGoeHLLirIR9HS+DAQFxoeEgeDSNF7IElEHEoA).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  datas = [
    {
      id:0,
      name: "first",
    },
    {
      id:1,
      name: "second",
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name: "third",
    },
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    const arrayOfName = this.datas.map(item => item.name); // Here
    console.log('arrayOfName', arrayOfName);
  }
}
```

`.map` will project what you return, so jut return the value you want.

Here is a [repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8rudm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)